# How can I can the scope which the onComplete function is called

Tags: fine-uploader

I have created a wrapper for the FineUploaderBasic class in order to link it in with my existing system and when the onComplete function is called it is called in the scope of the FineUploaderBasic element and not the parent element.

How can I change this or access the parent of the FineUploaderBasic Instance?

I have written the code using ExtJs as Follow's and I am trying to trigger my own upload complete event once the FineUploader upload has been completed. but the "onUploadComplete" function is being called within the scope of the FineUploader Instance and I am not able to access my own object.

```
Ext.define('X4.Core.FileUploader', {

mixins: {
    observable: 'Ext.util.Observable'
},

uploader: null,

constructor: function (config) {

    this.initConfig(config);

    this.mixins.observable.constructor.call(this, config);

    this.addEvents({
        /**
        * Event which is triggered once the file upload has been completed successfully.
        *
        * @since X4 4.1.1
        */
        "uploadcomplete": true
    });

    return this;
},

getUploader: function () {

    var me = this;

    if (me.uploader === null) {
        me.uploader = new qq.FineUploaderBasic({
            autoUpload: false,
            request: {
                endpoint: '/_system/x4/commands/file_uploader.ashx'
            },
            callbacks: {
                onComplete: me.onUploadComplete
            }
        });
    }

    return me.uploader;

},

onUploadComplete: function(id, name, response) {

    var me = this;

    alert('upload complete ' + id + ' ' + name + ' ' + response);

    me.fireEvent('uploadcomplete', me.callbackScope, id, name, response);

},

addFile: function (fileInput) {

    var me = this;

    return me.getUploader().addFiles(fileInput.extractFileInput());

},

upload: function () {

    var me = this;

    me.getUploader().uploadStoredFiles();

}

});
```

Comment: What do you mean by the "parent" element?  The context of the callbacks is always the Fine Uploader instance.  What are you trying to do exactly?  Can you edit your answer and provide some code so I can get a better idea of how I can assist?

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided any specific information about your problem, I'm going to have to provide a very generic answer.  Also, since you have not specified if you are using the jQuery plug-in or not, I'll have to assume that you are not.

So, the answer to your question really has nothing to do with Fine Uploader.  Assuming you are using the no-dependency version, Fine Uploader sets the context of the call to each callback/event handler to the associated Fine Uploader instance.  You are asking for the "parent" element, ostensibly the parent element of the value you have specified for the `element` option.

You can determine the parent of any element/node via the node's `parentNode` property.

Comment: The parentNode is undefined in the callback context. I am using FineUploaderBasic in the no-dependency version. I am adding the files manually using the addFiles Method then calling the uploadStoreFiles() method to trigger the upload.

Comment: @PhillipJones Edit your question to include all of your code then, please.